# How to parallelize a query in Apache Hive for a (small) dataset

Tags: mapreduce, parallel-processing, hive

I am testing the latest Hive on parts of my data set. It's only a couple GB of log files that I am reading through a custom SerDe.

When I run simple Group By queries (4 MR jobs), I am getting logs such as

- map : 100%
- reduce : 0%
- map : 85%
- reduce : 0%
- map : 86%
- reduce : 0%

all the while only using one core on the 8 core server. Kind of a waste...

I have activated the parallel option but it still won't parallelize. I have set the number of reduce jobs to be 8.

My expectations is that since my data set is partitionned (=> different files), at least some of the map-reduce phases could be run on parallel on those files.

Is my understanding wrong ? Is there a specific way to write the queries ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your doing nothing but a simple GROUP BY, the only real processing is comparison, which isn't that hard. That said, how many mappers are you running? The tasktrackers will not run parallelized. Rather, hadoop banks on multiple tasktrackers running to parallelize. So if you're only running one map task per node, you won't see anything.

Another possibility is that because your doing a GROUP BY, your bound in IO and not on processor, so there's no need to bring multiple cores into it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It turns out it was mainly because I was proof-testing in local mode so it wasn't launching multiple tasks at the same time. As soon as I changed to a pseudo-cluster and allowed it to run multiple maps & reduces in parallel as you suggested, it worked!